# How to use sequence as default value for ID in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

We have a table mapped in Fluent NHibernate with an Id generated by a Hilo sequence.

```
this.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo("seq_hp", "1000");
```

We now need to specify a Default value on the Id (set to the next sequence value) to make it work with a SQL Merge statement.

However, NHibernate will generate the sequence only after the tables are generated, so the next statement will fail because there is not (yet) a sequence.

```
this.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo("seq_hp", "1000")
                  .Default("next value for seq_hp");
```

Is there any way in NHibernate to specify the creation of the sequence before the creation of the table?
We are using Fluent mapping, but NHibernate's code or XML mapping solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way around is also feasable. Implement `IAuxiliaryDatabaseObject` to add the Default for the column using Sql. There is the base class `AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject` which does provide a default implementation.

Comment: Thanks but as I explained this solutions does NOT work. It creates the Table first before creating the Sequence. Do you have some more information about this IAuxiliaryObject? I can't find much when googling it.

Comment: I found it out and it works perfect. Easiest thing is to implement a class implementing the AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject. Thanks.

Comment: ah right, i misspelled it. Have fixed the answer and added the base class